# Do we know anything else about the Kledian Warlord besides his apparel fit preferences?

Tags: tv, advertisements

**Who is the Kledian Warlord and its Companions?**

The Kledian Warlord, his parrot-faced majordomo, and a Levi’s jean-wearing earth boy have a conversation about the boy’s jeans:

Richard Williams Studio for Levi’s produced the original advertisement first appearing in 1980, and the Kledian Warlord showed up several more times in later ads.

The commercial appears to capitalize on several pop culture fads at the time, including *Star Wars* and [*Heavy Metal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Metal_(film)).

Has either Levi’s or Richard Williams Studios ever detailed anything more about the group’s in-universe fiction, or anything more at all about these characters, whether in-universe or otherwise.

Comment: Title case for titles is killing readability for me