# Did Ralph McQuarrie design or complete concept designs for Levi’s Kledian Warlord commercial?

Tags: tv, advertisements

[Reference this thread](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254789/do-we-know-anything-else-about-the-kledian-warlord-besides-his-apparel-fit-prefe) for additional details about the “Kledian Warlord” advertisement for Levi’s jeans — widely described as a cross between *Heavy Metal* and *Star Wars*.

In ongoing search for more information about that commercial, I came across this gem of a revelation:
[image: Ralph McQuarrie is the Kledian]

In my years of Star Wars fandom, and my more recent attention towards apparel-related fantasy and sci-fi ads, I had never heard of any role played by McQuarrie in designing the Levi’s Kled.

Is this Youtuber correct — did Ralph McQuarrie produce concept/character designs for the Kledian Warlord advertisement?!?

Comment: I can't see any reference to McQuarrie. Most references seem to point toward Chris Blum as the original designer; http://www.spectacularoptical.ca/2013/08/psychedelic-interstitials/

Comment: Leans more towards early Don Bluth and Ralph Bakshi; McQuarrie not so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### YES — The Youtuber **IS** Correct!

[image: McQuarrie was prolific advertiser]

While it is true Ralph McQuarrie is best known for his *Star Wars* work, he got his start in graphic design and advertising, and continued a prolific career performing advertising work his whole life.

[BleedingCool noted](https://bleedingcool.com/comics/the-art-of-ralph-mcquarrie/):

> Ralph got his start in technical illustration working at Boeing and a number of small firms. In the 60s, he was hired to paint animation cels for CBS News Special Events coverage of the Apollo missions...

Dreams and Visions Press, the publisher of McQuarrie’s works, noted about their book, [The Art of Ralph McQuarrie: ARCHIVES](http://www.dreamsandvisionspress.com/archives-theartofralphmcquarriestandard.aspx), that:

> A 400+ page coffee table book featuring the largest collection of Ralph McQuarrie's art ever published. Best known for his instrumental contributions to the making of the original Star Wars trilogy, Ralph McQuarrie has inspired several generations of film fans and artists. While much of his Star Wars artwork has been reproduced in numerous volumes over the years, his non-Star Wars work has previously only been available in The Art of Ralph McQuarrie, a limited edition that we published in 2007.

[They additionally note about the limited edition book:](http://www.dreamsandvisionspress.com/archives-theartofralphmcquarrie-limitededitionred.aspx)

> At 13” x 9.5”, this 432-page volume contains more unseen art than what was in the original edition. That's hundreds of Ralph McQuarrie illustrations spanning all aspects of Ralph's career.

McQuarrie did a bunch of advertising work that most people may not ever have seen, because attention was focused on his Star Wars work.

[McQuarrie’s Kledian Warlord character design art appears in the promo video](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/970452904/the-art-of-ralph-mcquarrie-archives-art-book)
[image: McQuarrie’s Kledian]

Comment: Is there something in this video that confirms that these images are of the Kledian warlord?

Comment: Well beyond that Kled art speaking for itself, the video does not appear to have been made specifically to answer my stack exchange question.